# What's destroying my recently laid Kikuya lawn?

Tags: diagnosis, lawn, grass

About a month ago I had roll on Kikuya lawn planted. Since then the area has had a lot of rain and irrigation and everything seemed to be going okay until recently when portions started thinning out. Below are pictures of what I mean.

Here you can see the part that is thinning out vs. a healthier part. It seems to be spreading and started out as a much smaller area.
[image: Lawn for comparison]

Here is a close up of the grass at the troublesome area.
[image: Lawn closeup]

I have no idea what is doing this. I haven't been able to spot any pests or ants and have been very careful when mowing the lawn.

Is there any way to determine the cause?

Comment: If I only had the first picture to go on, I'd have thought it had been damaged by a mower or line trimmer. Could you post photos with a wider view? Got many rabbits in your area?

Comment: Looks like it's getting chewed off.

Comment: Way too short if a lawnmower was used on it. Grass needs enough top growth to keep the roots alive.

Comment: Does the ground rise up slightly to meet the paving in the picture, meaning the grass is laid on a slight slope in that part? Have you grasped the failing area and tried to lift it - it may be its not got good contact with the soil in that area. Have you used anything on the paving, like a cleaner or treatment, since the grass was laid?

Answer (score 2):

I would go easy on the mowing for a week or two. It looks like it was mowed too closely, or is being eaten by something. I've saved pieces like this with throwing a 50/50 mixture of compost and grainy sand over such areas, and then covering with a animal repellent (like thorny branches) and making sure it gets water.
But then again, it doesn't work for me ALL the time.